# Chromium Browser stopped working

Tags: chromium

Chromium Browser used to always work fine until today. I tried to run it and received the following error message:

```
/usr/lib/chromium-browser/chromium-browser: /usr/local/lib/libz.so.1: no version information available (required by /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcups.so.2)
/usr/lib/chromium-browser/chromium-browser: /usr/local/lib/libz.so.1: no version information available (required by /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgio-2.0.so.0)
/usr/lib/chromium-browser/chromium-browser: relocation error: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcups.so.2: symbol inflateCopy, version ZLIB_1.2.0 not defined in file libz.so.1 with link time reference
```

I even deleted it (`apt-get remove --purge chromium-browser`) and reinstalled it, and I still get the same error. What is the meaning of this and what can I do?

EDIT: This is on Ubuntu 14.04

Comment: What is the Ubuntu version?

Comment: My Ubuntu version is 14.04

Comment: /usr/local/lib/libz.so.1 could mean that you have self compiled software installed. Is that correct ? The libz version could conflict with the "default" one.

Comment: Yes that's possible. I had to self-compile a software which I ended up not using. Should I delete the file?

Comment: @albertj I removed said file and now everything works fine. Can you explain me how you knew that the problem was due to self-compiled software?

Comment: @AlphaOmega By default the /usr/local/ is used for installations that one compiles. Self compiled binaries would go in /usr/local/bin/ and libraries would go in /usr/local/lib/ When installing from packages, binaries often go in /usr/bin/ (Or /bin or /usr/sbin).